# Dplyr:: how to find sums for rows that partially share their name and keep them in the entire tibble?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

In the `mtcars` sample there are partially matching car names (in Mercedes there are `Merc 240D, Merc 230, Merc 280, Merc 280C, Merc 450SE, Merc 450SL, Merc 450SLC` etc). 
I would like to group them with the beginning of their name like `Merc 2*` and `Merc 4*`, count the sum of their `hp` by these groups and transform all the mentioned rows into rows called `Merc 2` and `Merc 4` leaving other non-Mercedes car rows in `mtcars` unmodified.
What is the best way of doing this?

Actually the only solution I have to date is:

```
    mtcars %>%
      rownames_to_column(var = "cars") %>%
      select(cars, hp) %>%
      mutate(hp = if_else(cars=="Merc 450SLC",
      sum(hp[which(.$cars == "Merc 450SL")], hp[which(.$cars == "Merc450SE")], hp[which(.$cars == "Merc 450SLC")]),
      hp))
```

Many thanks

Comment: maybe this thread helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993829/find-matching-groups-of-strings-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to change the names of the cars:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "cars") %>%
  mutate(cars = gsub("^(Merc [0-9]).*$", "\\1", cars)) %>%
  group_by(cars) %>%
  summarise(hp = sum(hp)) %>%
  as.data.frame
#                   cars  hp
# 1          AMC Javelin 150
# 2   Cadillac Fleetwood 205
# 3           Camaro Z28 245
# 4    Chrysler Imperial 230
# 5           Datsun 710  93
# 6     Dodge Challenger 150
# 7           Duster 360 245
# 8         Ferrari Dino 175
# 9             Fiat 128  66
# 10           Fiat X1-9  66
# 11      Ford Pantera L 264
# 12         Honda Civic  52
# 13      Hornet 4 Drive 110
# 14   Hornet Sportabout 175
# 15 Lincoln Continental 215
# 16        Lotus Europa 113
# 17       Maserati Bora 335
# 18           Mazda RX4 110
# 19       Mazda RX4 Wag 110
# 20              Merc 2 403
# 21              Merc 4 540
# 22    Pontiac Firebird 175
# 23       Porsche 914-2  91
# 24      Toyota Corolla  65
# 25       Toyota Corona  97
# 26             Valiant 105
# 27          Volvo 142E 109
```

Comment: Thanks! And what if I want to add some car's hp simultaneously to Merc 2 and Merc 4? Is it possible?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be possible, but you should open a new question for that. The comments section is not designed for extensive follow-ups, and opening a new question helps others who may have a similar question to find the answer.

Comment: Also, if this answer resolved your original question, please mark it as answered, thanks.